# Unable to install HP Deskjet 6122 printer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, compatibility

I suspect my printer is too old for Windows 7.

I have an HP Deskjet 6122, but it tells me that there are no drivers available.

How do I install it on Windows 7?

Comment: Someone posted a link to official HP drivers, but that badly formulated post was deleted (due to some flagging, I guess). Here goes: [HP Deskjet 6122 Driver Download](http://printer-driver-download.us/hp-deskjet-6122-driver-download/). That site is *not* HP, but when you copy & paste a link and ensure it starts with `ftp://ftp.hp.com/`, then you've got official HP drivers.

Answer (score 3):

don't know whether it is the oldest printer but i installed an ancient OKI Microline matrix printer on windows 7 :)

### Update

Now that you have made clear what you REALLY want, you may have a look at this:

How can I install my HP Deskjet 6122 printer? I'm using Windows Vista as my operating system.

HP is not providing a Windows Vista driver for the HP Deskjet 6122 printer. But there is an alternative way to get the printer working on Windows Vista. Just follow these steps:

1. If your printer is connected to your computer, disconnect it.
2. Click on the Start menu.
3. Click on Control Panel
4. Click on the Hardware & Sounds control panel.
5. Click Printers.
6. Click "Add a Printer"
7. Click "Add a Local Printer"
8. Check off the "Use an existing port" check box.
9. In the list entitled "Use an existing port" choose "LPT1: (Printer Port)
10. Click on the "Next" button
11. Choose "HP" as the manufacturer from the list of manufacturers
12. In the printers list that shows up, choose "Deskjet 990c"
13. Click on the "Next" button
14. In the text box called "Printer name" type "Deskjet 6122"
15. Wait for the computer to say that the printer has been successfully added.
16. Connect your printer to your computer (i.e. connect the cable to the USB port at the back of your computer.
17. A "Found New Hardware" screen should show up. Click Cancel on this window. (if it keeps showing up, just keep on clicking cancel until no more windows pop up)
18. Go back to the printer folder (i.e. the one where you clicked "Add a Printer"
19. Right Click on "Deskjet 6122"
20. Click on "Properties" in the menu that popped up.
21. Select the "Ports" tab.
22. Change the port from "LPT1" to "USB"
23. Click on the "Apply" button.

And that's it! That should allow you to use your HP Deskjet 6122 printer in Windows Vista.

*[Source](http://www.siliconguide.com/qa/forum/messages/2432.shtml)*

*The solution works for Vista, should be fine with Windows 7 too.*

Comment: Thanks Molly.  I have tried to install an Hp Deskjet 6122 and both my compter and the internet tells me that Windows 7 does not support this driver.  It is an old one at school (I am a teacher), but if I find another cheap old one I wont it to work!

Comment: Did I just type wont instead of want?  What a great teacher I am!

Comment: @Ryan McBride - if this doesn't work, feel free to post back :)

Comment: @Ryan, you might change 'recongnizable' to 'recognizable' also (I don't have the rep to edit here yet).

Comment: Thank you Molly.  I struggled, but it is working thanks to your instructions.  Ryan

Comment: @Ryan McBride - You're most welcome, feel free to accept the answer as correct then :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, the [HP Deskjet 6122 is compatible](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?type=Hardware&s=Hp%20Deskjet%206122) with Windows 7, both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Link broken.....